# Como retornar resultados de consulta ao Firestore dentro do método doInBackground?

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynctask, firestore

Estou trabalhando num aplicativo de Livro de Receitas pra aprender a usar os recursos do Firebase e estou trabalhando numa activity que deve listar todas as receitas já cadastradas pelo usuário.

As rotinas para gravar dados no banco estão funcionando perfeitamente, mas dei de cara com alguns problemas na hora de fazer a leitura desses dados, em suma eu recebo os dados do banco mas não consigo passá-los para a minha interface gráfica.

Vi que esse problema tinha como causa o delay que o Firestore tem para retornar os dados e que isso poderia ser resolvido através da implementação de paralelismo no código, e após ler um pouco sobre o tema tentei fazer a implementação de Async Task e de seus métodos mas não consegui resolver o problema.

Em suma, o método doInBackground retorna seu resultado e chama o método onPostExecute() (que por sua vez chama os métodos que alimentam a interface gráfica) antes de realmente receber os resultados do Firestore.

Na imagem abaixo, um print dos logs da app, dá pra ver que os métodos estão funcionando e sendo chamados na ordem correta, mas o doInBackground está retornando seus resultados antes de concluir a chamada ao banco.
Em amarelo estão os logs dos métodos do ciclo de vida da async task, em vermelho os resultados retornados pelo Firestore.

[image: Log que mostra a ordem dos retornos e de chamadas dos métodos do ciclo de vida da minha async task, além de mostrar o retorno]

Implementação da classe doInBackground()

```
    @Override
protected ArrayList<Receita> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    //leitura do banco
    db.collection("receitas")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d("Firestore:readRecepie", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                            Receita receita = document.toObject(Receita.class);
                            Log.d("Salvando a receita:", receita.getNome());

                            receitas.add(receita);
                            publishProgress();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w("Firestore", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

    //O problema está aqui, ele tá retornando essa lista antes de terminar a leitura do metodo interno
    Log.d("Async:doInBackground", "vai retornar o doInBackground");
    return receitas;
```

Answer (score 0):

O retorno da lista de receitas tem que acontecer dentro do

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {

    for (...) {

        ...

        receitas.add(receita);

    } 

    return receitas

}
```

Desse modo, após obter os dados da query com sucesso do Firestore e percorrer toda a lista do Firestore e adicionar os itens na lista receitas é que o resultado será retornado.

E como fica o retorno do método? Já que está alterando a posição da linha? 
Para isso, sugiro que você crie um objeto de resposta com sucesso e erro. 
Em sucesso retornar um data com a lista 
E em caso de erro retornar no else do if (task.isSuccessful()) {

Leia sobre MutableLiveData, talvez facilite com os tratamentos para consulta externas ou que tenham algum delay, e aí por exemplo atualização da sua activity somente quando a task do Firestore estiver terminada com sucesso ou erro